# How to use rgl package with a non-numeric axis

Tags: r, rgl

I want to use `rgl.surface(x,z,y...)` to draw a 3d graph.

However, my z axis is not numeric, like Mon, Tues, Wens....

So how can I use `rgl.surface`, or other functions to draw a graph?

Comment: the shape of your surface will depend of the (arbitrary) position on your `z` axis and I'm not sure that would lead to something you can use. Couldn't you plot separate curves (varying on `x` and `y`) for different `z`s instead? Why would you need to "unite" them in a surface?

Comment: So try and post a minimal example in the future and you will avoid those pesky downvotes (the upvote was from me - think it was a good question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert your axis to a numeric range, e.g.

```
 z <- c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed")
 zn <- seq_along(z)
```

You can then use zn in any plotting function.  You'll need to draw axes manually to include the appropriate labels.

For example,

```
 x <- y <- 1:3
 plot3d(x, y, zn, axes = FALSE)
 box3d()
 axis3d("x")
 axis3d("y")
 axis3d("z", at=zn, labels=z)
```

[image]